# Match mysql data type from python for load data

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script to load data to a mysql table problem that I am running into is following:

```
Warning: Incorrect integer value: 'user_id' for column 'user_id' at row 1
  +'VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
Warning: Invalid TIMESTAMP value in column 'edit_time' at row 1
  +'VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
```

and this is just a one line of many warning lines, I understand the error and based on my understanding I guess the row is still in the string format or the conversion didn't happen properly. I was thinking to cast each element in the row after I read them from tsv file.

```
example: int(row[0])
```

but I am not sure how to cast correctly to match MySQL timestamp type for the relevant timestamp element.

```
#load training data
def readtsv(file_name, con):
    cur = con.cursor()
    with open('file.tsv', 'rb') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'):
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable(user_id, article_id, revision_id, namespace, edit_time, md5, reverted, reverted_user_id, reverted_revision_id, delta, cur_size)'
                        +'VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
    try:
        con.commit()
    except Exception, e:
        print 'unable to commit'
        print e
```

Comment: we should see how your incorrect timestamp is formatted, or we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your timestamp value is the correct one?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

if it is so, MySQL will not see the error, thus no warning will exist!

As an hint simply print the insert statement string and try to launch it via "PhpMyAdmin" or other database interface tool.

The TIMESTAMP value, for MySQL is in the format: 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS', thus today 04 Dec 2012 21:06:00 will be written in this way: '20121204210600' with quotes!